# Why offtopic questions are just closed?

Tags: discussion

Why they are not also removed from the site?

If they are marked as offtopic they are not meant for the environment, should they be archived/removed from the public side of the website? How do they benefit the website by just being closed?

Comment: They get deleted, eventually. Not immediately, to give the asker a chance to fix their question and get it re-opened.

Comment: Some are not deleted, and never will because they are good questions, there is a subjective choice to make about the rule that define a quesiont as "off-topic"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many *do* get deleted.  Once the question is closed it's allowed to attract delete votes from users with the privilege to do so, and over time posts that are closed and that haven't been upvoted and that don't have upvoted answers will be automatically deleted.

The purpose of closure is to give the post author some time to fix the problems with the post.  If they're able to do so, the post can be reopened.  It is only after the author (and others) have failed to correct the problems with the post after a sufficient period of time, and assuming the post hasn't already collected content of value, that it is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

"Off-topic" is a very broad brush that we use to paint all questions which are put on hold.  However, that's not entirely true.  If the question is too broad, unclear or contains a debugging question without actual code to help us debug it with, then closure is the *right* thing to do and think about since it gives the OP a chance to fix problems with their question, similar to what Servy alluded to in their earlier answer.

However, the questions which are truly off-topic:

- Questions about some general piece of software/hardware,
- Questions about networking in a professional capacity,
- Questions which ask for some off-site resource (like books or tutorials), and
- Questions which can't be reproduced

...they get purged very quickly indeed.

Perhaps this is a call to change the verbiage around "off-topic", given that "off-topic" may mean "off-topic now but fixable for the future".